# Why NaiveBayesModel#predict returns category 0 when probability of classification is zero?

Tags: java, apache-spark, classification, naivebayes

I trained NaiveBayesModel with smoothing set to 0

```
NaiveBayesModel trainedModel = NaiveBayes.train(trainSetRdd, 0.0);
```

When I try to classifly something which **is not** in my training set, for example random word like "asdfksdflkj" such trained model should not classify it. What is strange it returns value 0 which I interpret as category with index 0. What is quite obvious I cannot make a distinction between correct classification with category 0 and classification with zero probability.

I think I misenderstood something but cannot figure out what. How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: There isn't much to go on here, but right now, I would suspect that since you set the smoothing term to zero, you wind up with a case P(B|A) = 0 - which in turn zeroes the posterior probability. Since you have a nonsense word, this case may occur for every single category. In that case, given that all class probabilities are equal, it outputs the first class it has - which is at index 0.

Comment: @user8407600 It makes sense, maybe you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I would, but it's an informed guess - I'd rather the actual answer was by someone who knows for sure. Still, thank you!